# No spacing between bootstrap labels

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In my application, I am trying to have several conecutive labels, like in this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/hesav/1):

[image]

Instead, I am getting this:

[image]

As you can see, no spacing is present between the labels. This is probably because of a problem in my CSS, but I am unable to find the culprit.

Where is the spacing between labels defined in bootstrap? Knowing that would allow me to narrow the bug-search in my CSS.

Comment: The jsbin looks ok to me.

Comment: The jsbin is ok - which is the default in bootstrap. The CSS in my application is breaking that (as seen in the second image attached), but I do not know how it is breaking it. I can not reproduce the problem in a jsbin because if I could, I would already have solved my problem, namely *which part of my CSS is breaking boostrap*. I would like to know how is the spacing between labels defined in bootstrap, so that I can narrow the search in my CSS.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your CSS at all. Just add a space or break the line between your ".label" tags.

This happened to me when the framework I use started to compress the HTML in order to save some bytes.

You can see this effect on this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/wezukupaxofi/2/edit).

[image: Bootstrap demo]

Answer (score 15):

You need to **remove** the space from **inside** the label.

The following spans have no space between each other:

```
<span class="label label-primary"> Primary </span>
<span class="label label-default"> Default </span>
```

The following spans have the correct spacing between them:

```
<span class="label label-primary">Primary</span>
<span class="label label-default">Default</span>
```

Notice that the leading/trailing white space must be removed from **inside** the span element for them to work correctly.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of that. Is is because there's already a space inside the span that the browsers remove the space outside the spans?

Answer (score 4):

I did this.

```
.label {
    margin-left: 5px; 
}
```

You can edit your bootstrap.css or edit less/labels.less and compile.

The space problem could be something in javascript code. I am testing without javascript from bootstrap.

Comment: The compression tools I was using kept removing the spacing. I ended up adding the margin in myself `.label { margin-left: 4px; }` and making sure to remove the margin from the first child to get the same outcome. `.label:first-child { margin-left: 0; }`

Answer (score 2):

The spacing between the labels (using `<span>`) is not defined in bootstrap, in fact, it's the default HTML CSS in-built into the browser.

I'm not sure what CSS could cause spacing like that between the `<span>` elements (leaving out padding and margin) but I **strongly** suspect the reason it's not applying in your case is because you have a `float:left;` somewhere added to your span elements.

Your problem replicated **[here.](http://jsbin.com/webecata/1/edit)**

Hence the solution is to use the inspector tool on the `<span>` element and find the line and erase where the `float:left;` is being added.

Comment: I am following your advice, but I do not think my case is a `float:left;` problem, but a `margin: 0px;` problem. The span has a *computed* `margin` property of `0 px`, but I am unable to find the original CSS rule that is causing that inheritance. Is it possible in Chrome to display the inheritance chain for a specific CSS property?

Comment: @jeckyll2hide If you see [here](http://jsbin.com/webecata/3/edit), `margin` of `0px` is in no way affecting the span element, unless you give in a negative amount. For checking the CSS properties of an element on chrome simply right-click on the span element and click on **Inspect Element**, the right side should show you the CSS properties  in a descending inherited order. More details about inspector tool [here.](http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs132/resources/inspector/)

Comment: I know about the Inspect tool (of course), but I am still lacking a simple way of narrowing the CSS property search to a single property, with full inheritance-chain display. This is somewhat available in the Chrome Inspector, but in such a way that *all properties* are displayed, making the bug hunting very complicated. If I am suspecting the `margin`, I should be able to **only** display the inheritance-chain for the `margin` property for the `span` element. This is not available, afaik.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide I'm not sure if you can search for a particular property on an element in inspector tool, but there's a way to check for margin and padding. While you have the `<span>` element selected in the inspector tool, click on **Computed** tab on the right (between _Styles_ and _Event Listeners_).

Comment: Sure, that is possible, and *that is why I know* that the margin in my span is 0 (because I have seen it as a computed property). I still can not easily identify the rule which is slipping through the inheritance chain, because I have so many rules. I have unchecked all margin rules which I *think* are *maybe* in the inheritance chain, but obviously I am missing some (**or Chrome has a bug!**), because it is still being shown as computed property for the span.

Comment: This would be **much** easier if I could really narrow the search to the inheritance chain of the margin property for the span element, which I think Chrome Inspector Tool does not allow.

Comment: @jeckyll2hide Not sure why it's being difficult to find the margin property (if it is applied), but if it is of any help, have you tried searching for it in the little text box below like [here](http://i.imgur.com/hOu4rsb.png)?

Comment: Thx, that's it! With that I can find the margin inheritance chain for the span! But even after disabling the property in the whole chain, it is still shown as computed, with value 0px. I guess Chrome Devtools has a bug then :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56171/discussion-between-i-can-has-kittenz-and-jeckyll2hide).